# Python: dynamic initialization of class members from strings holding expressions

Tags: python, dynamic, python-exec

This is a pretty general scenario, but to give some context, let's say I am using [cvxpy](https://www.cvxpy.org/) to do some constrained optimization. Now say I want to supply the objective function at runtime, such as `func` below:

```
import cvxpy as cp

class foo:
  def __init__(self,n,q,s):
    self.n,self.q,self.s=n,q,s
    self.K = len(n)
    self.x = cp.Variable(self.K)
    self.func = cp.sum(sum(self.n[j]*sum(self.n[i]*self.x[j] for i in range(self.K)) for j in range(self.K))
```

Of course, the function in the example is a contrived one, just to give you an example of
what sort
of string expression I am willing to supply as a command-line parameter,
just to avoid hardcoding stuff / changing the source code all the time. How I can override this `func` member's value with a new one, at runtime? I read about `exec`, but I am not sure if that helps. In short, I am willing to do something like `python my_awesom_prog.py "self.n[i]*self.n[j] for i in range(self.K) for range(self.K)"` and I would like the program behave as if this (horrible) string has been there as the definition of `func` in the first place.
EDIT: more to the point, I would like to have a method like this:

```
def reset_objective(mystring):
   self.func = interpret_as_cvxpy_entity(mystring)
```

Now, how to get hold of that `interpret_as_cvxpy_entity` API?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input()` and `eval()`. So, something like:

```
import cvxpy as cp

class foo:
  def __init__(self,n,q,s):
    self.n,self.q,self.s=n,q,s
    self.K = len(n)
    self.x = cp.Variable(self.K)
    self.func = eval(input())
```

Then you can run your script as `python my_awesom_prog.py` and `"self.n[i]*self.n[j] for i in range(self.K) for range(self.K)"` as the input.

I should warn you of the danger of `eval(input())`. For instance, you could input code within the eval function that deletes every file on your computer. For more info on why you shouldn't do this, I refer you to the following article:

https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html